# PyMongo - Clone Collection from another server

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm attempting to clone a collection on a remote server to my localhost with indexs using Python (as I'll have to be automating multiple tasks with this function using Python later on). From what I've read, using db.command would be the best way to approach this, but I can't seem to get it working, or even find what I'm really doing wrong.. Here's my code and error, any help is appreciated.

```
client = MongoClient()
db = clientProd.tools
colc = db.newDump

db.command({"cloneCollection": "databaseName.dump", "from": "example.com:6001"})
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dustin/Git/redbull_dev/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    dbProd.command({"cloneCollection": "databaseName.dump", "from": "example.com:6001"})
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.6.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/pymongo/database.py", line 396, in command
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.6.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/pymongo/helpers.py", line 147, in _check_command_response
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command {'from': 'example.com:6001', 'cloneCollection': 'databaseName.dump'} failed: no such cmd: from
[Finished in 5.2s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you looked at the doc from mongo, you should look at the doc from pymongo http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html

From that, the correct command should be:

```
db.command("cloneCollection", collection="databaseName.dump", from="example.com:6001")
```

### Edit

Since `from` is a python keyword, we probably need to create a dict and unpack it:

```
db.command("cloneCollection", **{'collection': "databaseName.dump", 'from': "example.com:6001"})
```

Comment: For some reason, "from" is giving me a syntax error, whether I put it before or after collection?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Pymongo itself due to 'from' not being able to be used.

Comment: the fact that `from` is a python keyword may be an issue here.

Comment: [cloneCollection cannot be used if the from server has authorization enabled](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/cloneCollection/#dbcmd.cloneCollection)

Answer (score 1):

I found that the selected solution didn't quite work (maybe version issue), this is my solution:

```
db_dest.command("cloneCollection", **{"cloneCollection": db_str + ".Sentence",
                                              'collection': db_str + ".Sentence",
                                              'from': mongodb_ip + ":27017"})
```